# Running react-tippy in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsfiddle

How can I run [react-tippy](https://github.com/tvkhoa/react-tippy/blob/master/dist/react-tippy.js) library in jsfiddle?

I get error message `Tooltip is not defined`, but script is imported.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLg4n2gg/)

Tooltip example

```
<Tooltip
  // options
  title="Welcome to React"
  position="bottom"
  trigger="click"
>
  <p>
    Click here to show popup
  </p>
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: Following your link the first function is `webpackUniversalModuleDefinition`, I only can guess that this lib can only run after transpiling though webpack... But it's just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issue. You are loading `UMD` module of reactTippy. So the module is not loading `Tooltip` in global scope. So you need to add below at the top of your JSFiddle

```
const Tooltip = reactTippy.Tooltip;
```

or

```
const {Tooltip} = reactTippy.Tooltip;
```

Next your also missing a `UMD` import of `popper.js`

https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.js

Below is the updated JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/uLg4n2gg/7/

[image: Working tooltip]

Answer (score 1):

Add this before you use the component:

```
const { Tooltip } = reactTippy;
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24qu94df/)

Alternatively, use `<reactTippy.Tooltip>...</reactTippy.Tooltip>`.

Comment: Thanks, but there is an error `_popper2.default is not a constructor`

Comment: Could you use a different env? https://codesandbox.io/s/nyq62yjmm doesn't give any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `Tooltip` to `reactTippy` to make it work.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLg4n2gg/3/)